# jQuery does not trigger click on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery that is supposed to be triggered when I click an element on my webpage. It works well with desktop however, it does not work on mobile/tablet devices. I have tried to use

```
jQuery(".myclassname").on('click',function (event){
//my code
});
```

I have also tried

```
jQuery(".myclassname").on('touchstart',function (event){
//my code
});
```

Also,

```
jQuery(".myclassname").on('vclick',function (event){
//my code
});
```

```
jQuery(".myclassname").on('tap',function (event){
//my code
});
```

However, nothing of the above mentioned works for mobile/tablet devices.
Any suggestions/help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you including the jquery library on the same page? Please may you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue?